# Passing Class to Function

Tags: dart

I’d like to pass the class `User` as second argument to the `load`-function.

Maybe someone knows how?

```
class App {
  Map<String, List<Model>> models = {
    'users': List<User>()
  };

  App() {
    load('users');
  }

  void load(resource) {
    Directory directory = Directory.fromUri(Uri(path: './app/data/' + resource));
    for (FileSystemEntity file in directory.listSync(recursive: false)) {
      Map<String, dynamic> fileContent = jsonDecode(File(file.uri.path).readAsStringSync());
      models[resource].add(User.fromJson(fileContent));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.
You can pass a `Type` object as argument, or a type as *type argument* (`load<T>(resource) { ... }`), but neither will allow you to call `User.fromJson` on the type.

What you can do is to pass the `User.fromJson` function as an argument (or, if that's a constructor, pass `(x) => User.fromJson(x)` as argument). That is:

```dart
void load(String resource, Object? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)) { 
  ... 
  map[resoruce].add(fromJson(fileContent));
}
```

and then

```dart
 load("someName", (map) => User.fromJson(map));
```